# JQuery Accordion with SharePoint 2010 Custom List

Tags: 2010, development, list, jquery, custom

I have a FAQ custom list in Sharepoint 2010 with two columns: Question (title column renamed) and Answer.

I want to display the questions and answers from the sharepoint list in JQuery Accordion. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aboud, 
actually, there are several ways how to accomplish this.

In your case when you have FAQ custom list, i am suggesting you to *create additional custom view for displaying list items in accordion*.

**Implementation**

A. Add custom view for FAQ list in Schema file (Schema.xml), below is provided source code for this View:

```
  <View BaseViewID="10" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="Accordion" DefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="Accordion.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">FAQ.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Title" ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" DisplayName="Question"  Sealed="TRUE"/>
          <FieldRef Name="Answer" ID="{b0747420-54bc-41b2-a1b3-8432f2dbdc70}"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
```

Please note that you have to change FieldRefs element properties to your own, i.e *ID*, *Name* and *DisplayName* for fields *Question* and *Answer*. Also note that i am referencing custom XSLT style sheet for rendering custom View that we have added before.

B. Implement XSLT style sheet for processing list items to display them using [Accordion (jQuery UI)](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). Complete source code for QAndA.xsl is shown below:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp"
  version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt x d asp __designer SharePoint ddwrt2"
  xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
  xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20"
  xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
  xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
  <xsl:import href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="View[@BaseViewID='10']" mode="full" ddwrt:ghost="always">
    <tr class="ms-viewheadertr"></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="accordionFAQ">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="RenderView" />
        </div>   
      </td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="footer" select="." />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template mode="Item" match="Row[../../@BaseViewID='10']" ddwrt:ghost="always">
    <xsl:param name="Fields" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="Collapse" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="Position" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="Last" select="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <h3>
      <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Title" />
    </h3>
    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Answer" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="FAQViewOverride" mode="RootTemplate" match="View[List/@TemplateType=11999]" ddwrt:dvt_mode="root">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#accordionFAQ" ).accordion();
      });
    </script>
    <xsl:call-template name="View_Default_RootTemplate"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Results**

Below is shown FAQ List View displayed as [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) for my case.

[image]

P.S. For more details, please see [this post](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/customize-the-rendering-of-a-view-in-list-view-in-sharepoint-2010-displaying-list-items-arranged-in-accordion/).

Answer (score 3):

My simplest approach was using  one Announcement list and jQuery tools (http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/accordion.html), plus one CEWP to include relevant scripts (stored in the a Library).

[image]

We ended-up building a simple web part using SPDataSource with a CAML query to load it.